# Problema con bucle for que recolecta nombres en C

Tags: c

Buen día a todos.

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto de la universidad donde estaba usando `scanf` en la función solicitar_informacion_peliculas, decidí cambiarlo por un `gets` para que tomara los espacios en los nombres que se ingresarán pero luego de ese cambio el for ignora el primer ciclo. ¿Cómo podría solucionar ese inconveniente?

```
/*
    POR TERMINAR...
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char nombre_pelicula [] [100];
int recaudo_pelicula [] [2];
int cantidad_peliculas = 0;
float recaudo_ciudad_1 = 0;
float recaudo_ciudad_2 = 0;

int main () {
    printf ("\n \t ------ Resumen Fondos Recaudados Ciudad 1 y Ciudad 2 ------ \n \n");
    nombre_pelicula [cantidad_peliculas] [100];
    recaudo_pelicula [cantidad_peliculas] [2];
    solicitar_informacion_peliculas ();
    solicitar_informacion_monetaria ();
    ventas ();
    promedio ();
    return 0;
}

void solicitar_informacion_peliculas () {
    int i = 0;
    printf (" Por favor ingrese la cantidad de peliculas a consultar  ");
    scanf ("%d", & cantidad_peliculas);
    for (i=0; i<cantidad_peliculas; i++) {
        printf (" Por favor ingrese el nombre de la pelicula #%d   ", i+1);
        gets (nombre_pelicula [i]);
    }
}

void solicitar_informacion_monetaria () {
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<cantidad_peliculas; i++) {
        printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el recaudo para la pelicula %s   \n", nombre_pelicula [i]);
        printf (" En la ciudad 1:   ");
        scanf ("%d", & recaudo_pelicula [i] [0]);
        printf (" En la ciudad 2:   ");
        scanf ("%d", & recaudo_pelicula [i] [1]);   
    }
}

void ventas () {
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<cantidad_peliculas; i++) {
        printf ("\n \n Taquilla de la pelicula %s para: ", nombre_pelicula [i]);
        printf ("\n Ciudad 1: $%d", recaudo_pelicula [i] [0]);
        printf ("\n Ciudad 2: $%d", recaudo_pelicula [i] [1]);
        printf ("\n El total recaudado por la pelicula %s fue de $%d", nombre_pelicula [i], (recaudo_pelicula [i] [0] + recaudo_pelicula [i] [1]));
        recaudo_ciudad_1 += recaudo_pelicula [i] [0];
        recaudo_ciudad_2 += recaudo_pelicula [i] [1];
    }
    printf ("\n \n El total de ventas que realizaron las %d peliculas fue de ", cantidad_peliculas);
    printf ("\n Ciudad 1: $%.0f", recaudo_ciudad_1);
    printf ("\n Ciudad 2: $%.0f", recaudo_ciudad_2);
}


void promedio () {
    printf ("\n \n El promedio realizado en vemtas de las %d peliculas fue de ", cantidad_peliculas);
    printf ("\n Ciudad 1: $%.2f", (recaudo_ciudad_1 / cantidad_peliculas));
    printf ("\n Ciudad 2: $%.2f", (recaudo_ciudad_2 / cantidad_peliculas));
}
```

Comment: En lenguaje C, los tamaños de las matrices no se pueden omitir y es lo primero que estás haciendo en esta línea: `char nombre_pelicula [] [100];`. Si te das cuenta, en la primera dimensión en ningún momento le indicas el tamaño de filas que tendrá la matriz. Lo mismo pasa con la matriz `recaudo_pelicula`. Lo que debes hacer es agregarle un tamaño fijo a esas dos matrices o si quieres obtenerlo en tiempo de ejecución, tendrás que usar matrices dinámicas. Por cierto, **nunca** uses la función `gets` está obsoleto y es peligrosa. Su reemplazo es la función `fgets` (para leer cadenas por teclado).

Comment: La única forma para omitir el tamaño, es inicializando la matriz, pero este no es el caso.